# Unable to select column with its header through XPath

Tags: xpath

My HTML

```
<table id="flex1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<thead>
<tr class="hDiv">
<th width="6%">
<div class="text-left field-sorting asc" rel="IFSC_CODE"> IFSC CODE </div>
</th>
<th width="6%">
<div class="text-left field-sorting " rel="BRANCH_NAME"> BRANCH NAME </div>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="sorted" width="6%">
<div class="text-left">SACS011151</div>
</td>
<td width="6%">
<div class="text-left">check</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="erow">
<td class="sorted" width="6%">
<div class="text-left">SACS011152</div>
</td>
<td width="6%">
<div class="text-left">Motiram</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="erow">
<td class="sorted" width="6%">
<div class="text-left">SACS011158</div>
</td>
<td width="6%">
<div class="text-left">TESTNAME</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My XPath

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[count(//table/thead/tr/th[.='BRANCH NAME']/preceding-sibling::th)+4]
```

Above XPath is Selecting all the column but not selecting its header name 'BRANCH NAME' and I want to select the header name with all its column.Any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use xpath union operator (`|`) to combine two xpath queries, for example* :

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[count(//table/thead/tr/th[.='BRANCH NAME']/preceding-sibling::th)+4]
    |
//table/thead/tr/th[.='BRANCH NAME']
```

*: <sub>formatted into multiple lines just to make it visible without horizontal scroll</sub>

Comment: well I use                                                                                                   //table/tbody/tr/td[4]  | //table/thead/tr/th[.='BRANCH NAME'] in firepath but still it is not selecting BRANCH NAME

Comment: //table/thead/tr/th[4]|//table/tbody/tr/td[4] this XPath Works.